# Date problem in Solaris 8

Tags: solaris, date

I tried to fix the date in the machine which has Solaris 8 as OS.
With the command `date`, I get the date repaired, but only for 2 seconds and reset in the time that I configured in the beginning:

**Example** : I configure the `date` to date MMddhhmmyyyy the time is 09:46 
so I get the right date right now but it does a loop for 2 seconds so it goes to 09:46:02 and reset to 09:46:00 that's all.

I think that problem is influenced by the behaviour of my machine because it's too slow when I want to restart or to launch an application.

When I launch prstat I got also this:

## prstat

```
   PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP       
   676 root     4336K 1864K sleep   59    0   0:00.00 0.0% sendmail/1
   673 root     7912K 5040K sleep   59    0   0:00.00 0.0% dtgreet/4
   654 root     6704K 2856K sleep   10    0   0:00.00 0.0% dtlogin/4
   652 root      203M   35M sleep   59    0   0:00.00 0.0% Xsun/1
   759 root     1688K 1368K cpu0    58    0   0:00.00 0.0% prstat/1
   411 root     5200K 2040K sleep   54    0   0:00.00 0.0% dtlogin/4
   743 root      336K  240K sleep   48    0   0:00.00 0.0% sh/1
   553 root     1856K 1136K sleep   54    0   0:00.00 0.0% ttymon/1
   562 root     1840K 1256K sleep   30    0   0:00.00 0.0% in.rlogind/1
   391 root     1944K 1296K sleep   51    0   0:00.00 0.0% nfsd/1
   388 root     2816K 2000K sleep   52    0   0:00.00 0.0% mountd/5
   524 root     3120K 1872K sleep   51    0   0:00.00 0.0% dmispd/5
   314 root     1752K  696K sleep   40    0   0:00.00 0.0% smcboot/1
   599 sideral  2576K 1840K sleep   48    0   0:00.00 0.0% bash/1
   312 root     1752K 1160K sleep   30    0   0:00.00 0.0% smcboot/1
   305 root     1080K  720K sleep   59    0   0:00.00 0.0% utmpd/1
   333 root     1056K  272K sleep    0    0   0:00.00 0.0% efdaemon/1
   261 root     2024K 1224K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% cron/1
   259 root     4344K 2120K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% syslogd/8
   276 root     2792K 1960K sleep    0    0   0:00.00 0.0% nscd/9
   322 root     2744K 2032K sleep   48    0   0:00.00 0.0% vold/6
   282 root     3184K 1016K sleep   50    0   0:00.00 0.0% lpsched/1
   243 root     1952K 1280K sleep    0    0   0:00.00 0.0% lockd/1
   238 root     2504K 1824K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% inetd/1
   245 daemon   2552K 1784K sleep    0    0   0:00.00 0.0% statd/3
   295 root     1480K 1064K sleep   30    0   0:00.00 0.0% powerd/5
   203 root     2264K 1120K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% rpcbind/1
    68 root     3496K 2648K sleep   52    0   0:00.00 0.0% picld/8
    58 root     2288K 1448K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% syseventd/12
   564 sideral  1520K 1120K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% csh/1
   246 root     3816K 1992K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% automountd/5
   561 root     3816K 2808K sleep    0    0   0:00.00 0.0% devfsadm/7
   555 root     1856K 1168K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% ttymon/1
   552 root     1864K 1112K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% sac/1
     1 root      864K  312K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% init/1
```

Is it normal? Anyone have any idea about that?

**EDIT** : even when i changed the motherboard, i got the same problem : Is any another hardware material is responsible for this error ?? because as i know only the motherboard is responsible of the date configuration !

Comment: What's the hardware?  SPARC?

Comment: @BowlOfRed yes ! the computer is a SUN Blade 1500

Comment: Can you take the system down and type the `watch-clock` prom command? That may help determine if you have bad hardware.

Comment: Have you checked the motherboard battery?  With hardware that's a decade old now, it's not uncommon for the battery for the system clock to be out of power.   It should be a CR2032 coin/watch style battery.

Answer (score 1):

If this is on SPARC, I suspect you have a hardware failure.

I've seen before where you could set the clock with `date` and it would work for one second.  Then on the next clock tick, date would go wonky (in my case by several years).  It really seemed like a single bit had failed and couldn't be modified.  This would fit if my failures were in a high bit and yours was a low bit.

In both the cases I saw, motherboard replacement solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BowlOfRed, but the problem it's that the motherboard replacement was done 1 month ago :/

Comment: Was the old hardware doing it as well, or has this appeared independently since the replacement? Similar discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/comp.unix.solaris$20date$20clock$20second/comp.unix.solaris/bJI_9YTzE-0/ChgUK_G_nnkJ

Comment: not sure it was the same problem before, but i got the same slow before so we changed the processor, motherboard and also the 2 memory slots

Answer (score 0):

Is NTP running?  That would change the time, and perhaps sync'ing to something where the time is off.  What does `ntpq -p` show?

Why was the motherboard replaced?  One of your comments hints because the box was slow but no indication of what "slow" means.  The SunBlade 150s weren't terribly beefy and used some commodity hardware so perhaps you're trying to run too much on the desktop?

The most useful portion of your prstat is missing which is the last line showing the # of processes, # of lwps, and load averages.  What is shown doesn't hint at as a utilization issue.  Perhaps a different hardware issue (ie: disk failing), or memory shortage?  So check `/var/adm/messages` and your scan rate in `vmstat`.